# RecyclerAdapter not shown because of the keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am changing the dataset of the recyclerview adapter with different search query results. I am able to populate the data as well but the populated data only shows if the keyboard is closed.

[This query("a") is valid but the result is shown only after I close the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWt8C.png)
[image]

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: Could you take a screenshot when the keyboard is closed? Also, are you saying that the data hides behind the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the keyboard as soon as the data is populated.

```
try {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
    getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);               
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: you may also want to add getcontext() or getacitivty() if its inside a fragment

Comment: No I can't hide the keyboard after the data is populated because with every text change new data will come which has to be populated